# WSO2CEP 3.0.0 error when selecting output attributes using custom functions in execution plan

Tags: wso2

In execution plan, if a custom function is called when selecting attribute other than the last one, a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown. If this custom function is called when selecting last attribute, then no exception occurs. Let me clarify this with an example.

I have streams defined inStream = [name, surname, address] and outStream = [name, surname, address] to be used as input and output stream, respectively. I have written a custom function that concatenates strings. When I use it like below in an execution plan (custom function is used when selecting the last attribute),

```
from inStream
select name, surname, ns:concat('Address is: ' , address) as address
insert into outStream
```

I get outStream = ['Micheal' 'Jackson', 'Address is: Indiana'] for inStream = ['Micheal', 'Jackson', 'Indiana']. However, when I change the query to

```
from inStream
select ns:concat('Name is: ', name) as name, surname, address
insert into outStream
```

i get the exception. Is this a bug? How should I handle the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be a bug. Created a [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-641) and attached the fix as well. This will definitely be fixed in the next version. If you want the fix to be available immediately, you can checkout the [Siddhi code](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/commons/siddhi/2.0.0-wso2v4/) and apply the patch given in JIRA and copy the relevant jar (siddhi-core_2.0.0.wso2v4.jar in this case) to repository/components/plugins folder of your CEP server instance.

As a workaround, you can use the custom function at the end and then swap the attributes to your required order by passing the output of this query to a different query which simply swaps the attributes to the required order (If events are going out of the CEP, then you may be able to do this reordering at the event formatter level as well).

HTH,

Comment: Is it enough to put patch file in <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/components/patches ? Do I have to apply to patch to code, recompile and extract the jar?

Comment: You have to apply the patch to source, recompile the jar and replace the existing jar inside <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/components/plugins. (Patching by simply putting the source patch inside the <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/components/patches won't work.)

Comment: Without -Dmaven.test.skip=true option I could not compile the code. The error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project siddhi-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] **\2.0.0-wso2v4\modules\siddhi-core\src\test\java\org\wso2\siddhi\test\standard\table\rdbms\BasicDataSource.java:[30,7] error: BasicDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in CommonDataSource. With skipping test, produced jar name was siddhi-core-2.0.0-wso2v4. I had to change it, too. The patch worked, anyway.